# How to access UEFI on Sony Vaio if "Operating System Not Found"

Tags: operating-systems, hard-drive-recovery

The hard disk in my old Sony Vaio laptop died and I'm trying to reinstall Windows 10 Pro on an SSD that I bought to replace the dead HDD. I found an [official ISO download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), but the problem is the laptop goes straight to the "Operating System Not Found" black screen as soon as I turn it on, even if I have a bootable CD or USB inserted, and I cannot press F2 or any other key to access the UEFI.

Am I royally screwed, or is there a way to salvage this situation? I'm thinking about putting the ISO directly onto the SSD (after formatting it as a bootable drive), connecting the SSD to the laptop, and crossing my fingers. Let's say it boots into Windows 10 setup -- with my old HDD dead, would it still be able to retrieve my license somewhere and activate (it was upgraded from Windows 8 Pro)?

Comment: What you propose (by putting the ISO on the hard disk and booting) will fail 100%. Do not waste your time on this. Personally, if you're getting nowhere with boot devices then I would temporarily remove the hard disk/SSD from the laptop, make sure there's no DVDs or memory sticks inserted and boot. The fact there's no boot devices the BIOS/UEFi should, ultimately, identify there's no boot device and offer you the chance of getting to the setup. Here you can then check to make sure the boot settings are right for you.

Comment: @Kinnectus thanks for the warning. I was planning to put the ISO on the SSD, not the HDD. In any case, I did as you suggested (disconnected HDD) and when I turn it on it still goes straight to the "Operating System Not Found" error. I cannot find a way to access UEFI at all. I know the HDD is dead because it's not detected anymore in Disk Management when I connect it to a HDD dock attached to another laptop (the SSD is detected but unformatted).

Comment: What happens if you power off the laptop (press and hold power button for a few seconds) then press the "ASSIST" button ONCE... some sourcess ay this might boot the laptop and give you ability to access BIOS/UEFI

Comment: @Kinnectus what a great tip -- it worked! I've done this before but totally forgot that it needs to be pressed from off (I was pressing Assist at the splash screen instead). Now I have two options: 1. Recover from the recovery partition (Windows 8), then upgrade to Windows 10 again. 2. Put the Windows 10 ISO on a bootable USB and use that instead. Actually, now that I can boot from USB, I'll use Ultimate Boot CD to see if I can fix the HDD through software (e.g. corrupt MBR).

Comment: P.S. You should repost your Assist button comment as an answer so I can accept it :-).

Comment: Much easier just to bung the blank SSD in -> boot from the bootable USB or DVD -> Install Windows from scratch. Leave the old HDD and use the likes of a hard disk caddy to recover data/medle as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony VAIO laptops have the <kbd>ASSIST</kbd> button that should be pressed **whilst the computer is powered off** (i.e. press and hold the power button until the computer forcibly turns off or shutdown Windows if you can get to Windows).

This should allow the computer to boot and may give you the ability to enter the BIOS/UEFI interface.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title to reflect my better understanding of the situation.